# Drupal Custom Search Results Per Content Type

Tags: views, theming

So I have a View that is a list of all content on my site. I have an exposed form in a block that is "Search Terms". I have a custom template for my view to customize the results page. I have a couple of content types including "Products" and "Locations".

I'd like the Products to be displayed in a grid format with their corresponding product images and the Locations to be displayed in a list with a corresponding map. What would be the best way for me to accomplish this?

Comment: From the way you have framed the question it sounds like both types of content can appear on the page at once, which makes the question unanswerable. So presumably your exposed form also includes a content type selection?

Comment: Why does having both content types on a single page make this question unanswerable? This scenario exists in 99% of all Drupal sites as it is the base template of all site searches. Check out https://drupal.org/search/site/captcha?f[0]=ss_meta_type%3Amodule. Couldn't this page be customized?

Comment: As I understood it you want both on the same page? You can't normally have a grid and a list in a single result set.

Comment: Or rather, you can, but it tends to look a mess.

Comment: OK, I think I see what you are asking for now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sketch of an answer: in a views template for the result set you will have access to the original results in $view->result. If the view is set up for fields output, and includes all the fields required including content type, you can iterate through it 3 times, each time ignoring entries that have the content type you don't want for that case.

It's quite hard to come up with clean-looking code because of the way that views names the field data, but if you don't mind that, you can use the dpm() function of the Devel module to inspect it then code accordingly.